# Discrete Fourier transform for odd function

Tags: python, numpy, fft, pyfftw

I have an initial function `u(x,0) = -sin(x)` and I want to derive the FFT coefficients for an odd-parity solution in the form of `u(x,t) = $\sum_{k \geq 1} a_{k} sin (kx)$`. I tried using the normal expansion of the function in terms of `$\exp{ikx}$` but it adds some error to the solution.

Can anyone suggest me the procedure of how to filter the Fourier coefficients which remains odd throughout the solution using `numpy.fft.fft` ?

Comment: You are looking for Discrete Sine Transform: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.dst.html?

Comment: Thanks. I have a function `-sin(x)` for which I take a forward `dst` and on inverting using `idst`, I don't get the same `-sin(x)` profile.

Comment: I think your problem is somewhere else, can you post all your code? even fft should give you only the sine part coefficients if the function is `-sin(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is inherently odd (like the sine functions) then only the imaginary part of the `fft` function will be non-zero. I think your problem is that your function is not periodic as it should be, you should exclude the last point:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,50,endpoint=False)
y=-np.sin(x)
yf=np.fft.fft(y)
even_part=yf.real
odd_part=yf.imag
```

Here only `odd_part[1]` is non-zero.
If your function is not odd and you want to force it, you can either use `sdt` as I mentioned in the comments, or add the inverse of your function on left side then use `fft`.

Another point, if your input is not complex, then it's faster and more time efficient to use `rfft`

Comment: Thanks @anishtain4 . Indeed the function is periodic. My input is real, so I am using `numpy.fft.rfft`.

Comment: What I meant by "not periodic" is that if you calculate `sin(x)` from `-np.pi,np.pi` "including the last point" then the generated function is not periodic contrary to what you think.